# ¿Como puedo conectarme a una base de datos mysql en c# usando Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2017

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de escritorio en **Visual Studio 2017** y tengo problemas al conectarme a la base de datos **mysql**, ya hice la conexion a la base de datos en el explorador de servidores [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] El código del boton que ejecuta el código de la conexión es el siguiente:

```
 private void btn_acceder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txt_usuario.Text != "" && txt_pass.Text != "")
        {
            clsLdap cls = new clsLdap();
            cls.login();
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("Credenciales incorrectas","Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

El metodo `login()` es el siguiente:

```
public bool login()
    { 
        try
        {
            string server = "192.168.65.66", database = "asistencia", user = "root", pass = "root";

            MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection("server=" + server + "; database=" + database +
                "; Uid=" + user + "; pwd=" + pass + ";");
            conexion.Open();

            MessageBox.Show("Conexión correcta");

            conexion.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            return false;
        }


    }
```

Cuando ejecuta la línea `conexion.Open()` ocurre una excepcion y pasa para el `catch()`

Comment: ¿Cuál es la excepción que ocurre?

Comment: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Comment: Si usas alguna tool de admin de mysql, usando esos datos que tienes para el connection string puedes conectarte? porque esta claro por el mensaje que no esta pudendo resolver el server mysql, quizas hay algun firewall que este bloqueando el acceso al puerto

Comment: Si uso **pgAdmin** con estos datos de conexión y me puedo conectar sin ningun problema.